# React: App height only half of page after setting HTML, Body and App to 100% height

Tags: css, reactjs

My App's background photo goes only to half of the page. It seems to be limited to the length of the components, even though I had attempted to separate that with my code.

I have already set HTML, Body, and the App component to a height of 100% in my App.css file. But the result is my app background taking up only half of the screen.

App.js file

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <Logo />
        <Rank />
        <ImageLinkForm />
        <FaceRecognition />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.css file

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.App {
  background: url('/assets/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

button, link {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I had originally set the .App portion of my css file to body so that the App's background would cover the page, but I would like to be able to further modify the background image alone, which I can't do if the image is within the body.

I want my background photo to be the only thing manipulated, not the entire body of my site.

Comment: Your background needs to change. Check with a background colour if it covers the whole page.

Comment: It might be good to put `outline: 1px solid;` on `.App` just to see if the div is covering the whole viewport.

Comment: try with `height: 100vh` instead of `height:100%`

Comment: @Alberto your answer solved my issue. If you want, you can put it as an answer so I can properly give you credit for this!

Comment: @rpivovar Thank you for the tip I appreciate it. I will keep this in mind for future projects.

Comment: @A-Bro Did you check out my answer for fixing it right?

Comment: @A-Bro The `vh` might not be the right solution. You'll know why soon. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `height: 100vh;` instead of `height: 100%;`. This will force your elements to adapt to the full ViewHeight

Answer (score 2):

Ah your are right! It's the `#root`! I have also added `overflow: hidden;` to `.App` for collapsing the margins.

```css
#root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Look at the [CodeSandbox preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/w756jx6x0w):

[image: preview]

Comment: Based on how CRA is set up and how the OP's original question is asked, this should be the accepted answer. I will also add that if setting `#root{height:100%;}` doesn't solve your problem, try to investigate from index.js (where the root node is attached) down. If you have any subsequent components that employ div wrappers, it is critical to also set those to a height of 100% if you want children components to have access to the full height of the body. This is something easy to look over, so just in case it helps!